# Why does this Excel column contain non-numeric data?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016, format, data-analysis

I have an Excel column that had a list of ages, with several empty cells more or less evenly distributed along the column. I tried to use the Data Analysis Toolkit add-in to get Descriptive Statistics for the `Age` column, but got a message that the column contains non-numeric data. I then used an IF function to output 0 when an `Age` cell is blank, and I copied the function output column, then pasted values, to ensure nothing could think the new column contained anything non-numeric. The column now looks like this, and contains only numeric values and no formula:

[image]

My main concern here is that the non-zero values look like text values, and Excel always treats text values as text, even if they only contain numerics. What have I done wrong or not done in trying to make this `Num Age` column only numeric? What I did was select all 812 cells in the column only, and apply the following format:

[image]

I really expect every cell in that column to be numeric, yet the left aligned, non-zero numbers behave like text values (left align), where only the zero values behave like numerics, and the Data Analysis Toolkit won't give me Descriptive Statistics because the column contains non-numeric values.

Comment: I don't know the trick in excel, but paste the values to notepad and copy from there. Then paste them back into Excel (making sure your column is already formatted as number before pasting back).

Comment: @Isolated Thanks, that's a cool trick I often use to format other data but never thought of for Excel. I do still, however, want to know the _trick_ in Excel, or rather how to do this properly. It's such a common requirement it shouldn't require any special tricks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Text to Columns in probably your best best (as it doesn't impact blank cells), but some other options depending on what you working on.

Highlight the data of interest. Anyways click on the little box that comes up in the corner and convert to number.

[image]

Another trick is in another cell enter 1. Click on this cell then press Ctrl&C. Highlight the cells right click and select Paste Special.

[image]

Then select multiple and Ok.

[image]
[image]

The other fairly quick option is in another column add formula multiplying the value in the first by 1.  Then copy and paste values back over.

Hopefully, this adds to your Excel tool box.

Answer (score 1):

Just found way to convert text to numbers with relative ease. Highlight the column that currently has your numbers stored as text. Then, click the Text-to-columns button on the data tab. Then click FINISH. It should automatically fix your cell format.

Here, column A is the before, while column C is the impact of using this trick.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, man!